# My fan has become crazy!

Tags: sound, cpu, overheating, fan, temperature

I just got a serious problem! Today when I turned on my laptop, the fan (I suppose is the CPU or GPU fan) went crazy! I hear the sound like it is spinning at 4000/5000 rpm. The other strange things is that the sensors (I use Psensor) tell me that the fan is around 2200/2400 rmp.

All the temperatures, disk, cpu, etc. are OK and in their average ranges. I didn't find anything for managing the fan speed directly, but for the moment it's a bit annoying cause the fan it's making so much noise!

My laptop is an ASUS X551C. I've had it from 2013 and I cleaned it well more or less two years ago when I mounted an SSD.

Can someone please help me?

**Update** The problem seems to appear when the rpm are from 2200 to 2400 cause when the fan reach 1600/1700 rpm the noise is absent, could be only dust? I don't understand why this problem went out suddenly

Comment: Check if some program is running at 100% CPU (use top or htop).

Comment: @SebastianStark Everything seems ok

Here the snap -> https://imgur.com/a/NapCc

Comment: Two things:  1) you can try to change the fan settings in your bios to help debug when it happens an to make sure there is still propper fan control. 
2) It could be something is getting into the fan as you mention, I had done some work on a fan I had, it was fine for a while but later a piece of tape I had come loose as started making a much louder sound, maybe you have something like that that is just getting pulled in at higher fan speeds?

Comment: @Jeff I just see into the bios and all seems OK. Surely should be the option 2, for now I've to live with this noise, but I'm so convinced that is an "Hardware" problem. So as soon as possible I think I've to unmount my pc and see what is the real problem :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fancontrol, verify that it is actually starting properly.  It is possible for the hwmon paths to change between boots which would cause fancontrol to fail and leave the fans running at full speed.  Take a look at `/etc/fancontrol`, if it is there and there is content, make sure the paths referenced there are correct.